# Lack of text in menus and software in Debian

Tags: debian, hidden

At the time of installing the software in Debian 12, according to the attached image, the menu text is not readable at all, what should I do?
what's the solution?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90cE7.png)

The graphics card has been updated.

Comment: welcome to [so], a forum for programming questions. your problem seems to be unrelated to *programming* (and more about configuring your desktop), so i suggest migrating it to [su] or [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com).